# What is the type of a very simple unwrap function for a transformed monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I am exercising with monad transformers as presented in http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~nhn/MGS2006/LectureNotes/lecture03-9up.pdf

I have an implementation for an **error transformer** which reads like:

```
newtype ET m a = ET (m (Maybe a))
deriving instance Show (m (Maybe a)) => Show (ET m a)
```

(Actually this looks to me like `MaybeT`, but ok...)

I wish to specify a function to unwrap `ET`'s. This function is given in the paper and does its job even without type declaration:

```
unET (ET m) = m
```

The thing is that **I am uncapable to specify its type explicity**. If I prepend a type which seems reasonable to me:

```
unET :: (Monad m) => ET m a -> m a
```

the error message is `Could not deduce (a ~ Maybe a) from the context (Monad m)`

What is the type of the `unET` function?

I have already tried the magic compiler spells `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, `MonoLocalBinds`, which I've found in answers to similar questions. Still no joy.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Have you tried running `:t unET` in ghci?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just look at the definition:

```
unET (ET m) = m
```

you know that the only field of `ET` has type: `m (Maybe a)`. The `unET` function takes an `ET m a` and returns its only field, so the return type of `unET` must be the type of the field, i.e. `m (Maybe a)` and *not* `m a`!